# Cannot use Service Stack inside a PCL

Tags: xamarin, servicestack, servicestack-text

I am using Xamarin and need to use a PCL

However, I cannot install ServiceStack into the PCL other than the PCL package which is classed as no longer being maintained

Has anyone come across this?

I want to use PCL because I dont want to duplicate code

PCLs are supposed to be supported via the latest Service Stack but this does not appear to be the case

I have code which makes use of ToJson which is in ServiceStack.TExt

I know I could create a folder inside my iphone (and android) assemblies but I am not sure this is a good approach because it doesnt feel right (everything all in one place instead of in proper layers)

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions aren't correct, [ServiceStack PCL Packages](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) ARE still being maintained, but instead of being maintained in individual packages, e.g:

- <s>ServiceStack.Client.Pcl</s>
- <s>ServiceStack.Text.Pcl</s>
- <s>ServiceStack.Interfaces.Pcl</s>

They have now been merged as different profiles into the main client NuGet packages, e.g:

- [ServiceStack.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client)
- [ServiceStack.Text](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text)
- [ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Interfaces)

Comment: I tried referencing ServiceStack.Client and get the error - Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.34'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author. If I use the Package Manager Console, service stack does install into my iphone assembly

Comment: @Paul than you're trying to reference inside an [incompatible PCL Profile](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#portable-class-library-support), i.e. ServiceStack.Client only supports Profile7 i.e. iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.5.

Comment: Hmmmm not sure how to get round this? I created the pcl with visual studio?

Comment: Thanks this works now you cant use Silverlight in the PCL - that was causing the problem

Comment: I think you may need to look at using shared projects instead

Comment: @Paul Thanks I know what I'm doing now